# PDO returning null object when SQL query returning data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, pdo

When I query my long query to MYSQL directly I get right data

But then I use PDO with same query I get no data (Object size zero) . Following data

**SQL Statement :**

```
SELECT table1.field1,table2.field1 FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.key = table2.key AND table2.field2 ='coffee' AND (table2.date BETWEEN '2014-1-1' AND '2014-12-1');
```

I get desire output when i directly run the query on mysql.

However, when I run using php file having following content I get nothing

```
include 'config.php';
$query = 'SELECT table1.field1,table2.field1 FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.key = table2.key AND table2.field2 ='coffee' AND (table2.date BETWEEN '2014-1-1' AND '2014-12-1')';
$stmt = $db->query($query)->fetchAll();
var_dump($stmt);
```

output is

```
array(0) { }
```

I also tried

```
$query = "SELECT table1.field1,table2.field1 FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.key = table2.key AND table2.field2 ='coffee' AND (table2.date BETWEEN '2014-1-1' AND '2014-12-1')";
```

and

```
  $query =  ' SELECT table1.field1,table2.field1 FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.key = table2.key AND table2.field2 = \'coffee\'  AND (table2.date BETWEEN  \'2014-1-1\'  AND  \'2014-12-1\' )' ;
```

and

```
$query =  ' SELECT table1.field1,table2.field1 FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.key = table2.key AND table2.field2 = \'coffee\'  AND  \( table2.date BETWEEN  \'2014-1-1\'  AND  \'2014-12-1\'\)' ;
```

and

```
$query =  " SELECT table1.field1,table2.field1 FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.key = table2.key AND table2.field2 = \'coffee\'  AND  \( table2.date BETWEEN  \'2014-1-1\'  AND  \'2014-12-1\'\)" ;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show config php and the actual query

Comment: Use `$stmt = $db->query($query);` `$stmt->fetchAll();`

Comment: Probably a bad plan to use the same quotes for values and your PHP string.

Comment: Are you connected to the same database?

Comment: The config.php main code is :    try {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};port={$port};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username,$password);
        
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex){
        die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                                                 And yes, I am connecting to the same database as the config.php is common.

Comment: I wasted tonnes of hair and hrs on this and Finally got it working as using prepare and execute funtions of PDO . [SOLVED]